# Argo Rollouts using kube configmap in blue/green deploy strategy

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, configmap, argo-workflows

I am trying to setup blue green deploy strategy for our kube app using [argo rollouts](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/index.html). Currently our app has two pods running in same namespace

1. grpc server
2. worker

grpc server uses the connection url specified in kube configmap to connect to worker pod.

Now when I change the deployment type to argo rollout and setup [blue/green](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/features/bluegreen.html) strategy, i am stuck on how to specify the different configmap for blue/green pods. Meaning, in my case blue grpc server need to talk to blue grpc worker and green with green using different configmap entry connection url string.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Based on the [rollout spec](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/features/specification.html), it uses regular deployment spec - `# Template describes the pods that will be created. Same as deployment` which means you can specify your config map in deployment section there. Depending on your case, it can be done different - please refer to [Configure a Pod to Use a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).

Comment: @moonkotte, thank you for the reply. currently I already refer to the configmap in the spec. The problem is have is how can I use different configmap for blue/green service at run time.